# What does the "map" method do in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, dictionary, range, enumeration

What does `.map` do in:

```
params = (0...param_count).map
```

Comment: Ask *one* question at a time. `map` is a common "functional" method found on Enumerable objects used for transforming the values in a sequence (with special considerations). `..` and `...` are ways of creating ranges. Also, *get familiar* with the REPL, where you can try this stuff out yourself! :)

Comment: REPL for ruby is irb, for Rails it is rails c. REPL allows you to test code directly against the language shell itself.

Answer (score 458, accepted):

The `map` method takes an enumerable object and a block, and runs the block for each element, outputting each returned value from the block (the original object is unchanged unless you use `map!)`:

```
[1, 2, 3].map { |n| n * n } #=> [1, 4, 9]
```

`Array` and `Range` are enumerable types. `map` with a block returns an Array.  `map!` mutates the original array.

Where is this helpful, and what is the difference between `map!` and `each`? Here is an example:

```
names = ['danil', 'edmund']

# here we map one array to another, convert each element by some rule
names.map! {|name| name.capitalize } # now names contains ['Danil', 'Edmund']

names.each { |name| puts name + ' is a programmer' } # here we just do something with each element
```

The output:

```
Danil is a programmer
Edmund is a programmer
```

Comment: thanks speransky for the example. then how is .map different from .each?

Comment: Ahhh I get it. So .map actually mutates the array while .each just loops through the array to access the values while leaving the original array untouched?

Comment: I don't think so. `each` and `map` works the same way, but while `each` is an iterator only, `map` has `map!` form, which mutates an  object given. Also `map` has a `collect` synonym with no differences.

Comment: @SperanskyDanil, it is about @Edmund's comment, which you could see right above mine, for this part: "So .map actually mutates the array while .each just loops". `#map` actually doesn't mutate anything, `#map!` does.

Comment: It is hazardous for casual readers that the opening sentence describes `map` as though it were `map!`

Comment: wasn't wrong, could just be a little more explicit.  Updated Q

Comment: to see the difference between map and each, open an IRB window and look at the results for y and z in the following code: y = [1,2,3].each {|x| x + 1}; z = [1,2,3].map {|x| x + 1}

Comment: @davej: Whoa, I got different answers from both of them, but I  didn't understand why is this so?

Comment: @Inquisitive: 'each' returns the array that calls it (in the example, [1,2,3]) when a block is supplied, 'map' returns a new array populated with the values calculated by the block. This might help: set the variable ary = [1,2,3], and check out it's object_id.  Then run y = ary.each {|x| x + 1}; z = ary.map {|x| x + 1}.  Now check the object_id's of y and z.  y has the same object_id as ary (because each returned ary), but z has a different object_id, because map returned a new array.

Comment: great answer, thanks! This inspired a visual answer for visual thinkers, also trying to remove some confusion around `map` and `map!`, see below https://stackoverflow.com/a/66869517/5925094

Answer (score 71):

`map`, along with `select` and `each` is one of Ruby's workhorses in my code.

It allows you to run an operation on each of your array's objects and return them all in the same place. An example would be to increment an array of numbers by one:

```
[1,2,3].map {|x| x + 1 }
#=> [2,3,4]
```

If you can run a single method on your array's elements you can do it in a shorthand-style like so:

1. To do this with the above example you'd have to do something like this

   ```
   class Numeric
     def plusone
       self + 1
     end
   end
   [1,2,3].map(&:plusone)
   #=> [2,3,4]
   ```
2. To more simply use the ampersand shortcut technique, let's use a different example:

   ```
   ["vanessa", "david", "thomas"].map(&:upcase)
   #=> ["VANESSA", "DAVID", "THOMAS"]
   ```

Transforming data in Ruby often involves a cascade of `map` operations. Study `map` & `select`, they are some of the most useful Ruby methods in the primary library. They're just as important as `each`.

(`map` is also an alias for `collect`. Use whatever works best for you conceptually.)

**More helpful information:**

If the [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html) object you're running `each` or `map` on contains a set of Enumerable elements (hashes, arrays), you can declare each of those elements inside your block pipes like so:

```
[["audi", "black", 2008], ["bmw", "red", 2014]].each do |make, color, year|
  puts "make: #{make}, color: #{color}, year: #{year}"
end
# Output:
# make: audi, color: black, year: 2008
# make: bmw, color: red, year: 2014
```

In the case of a Hash (also an `Enumerable` object, a Hash is simply an array of tuples with special instructions for the interpreter). The first "pipe parameter" is the key, the second is the value.

```
{:make => "audi", :color => "black", :year => 2008}.each do |k,v|
    puts "#{k} is #{v}"
end
#make is audi
#color is black
#year is 2008
```

**To answer the actual question:**

Assuming that `params` is a hash, this would be the best way to map through it: Use two block parameters instead of one to capture the key & value pair for each interpreted tuple in the hash.

```
params = {"one" => 1, "two" => 2, "three" => 3}
params.each do |k,v|
  puts "#{k}=#{v}"
end
# one=1
# two=2
# three=3
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me in irb.  I get `NoMethodError: private method 'plusone' called for 1:Fixnum` in ruby 2 and 'wrong number of args' in ruby 1.9/1.8.

Anyway, I used a lambda: `plusone = ->(x) { x + 1 }` then take out the symbol specifier: `[1,2,3].map(&plusone)`.

Comment: hmm sounds like you declared `private` inside of the class where you put your method before you put your method

Comment: Yeah, it totally does.  Except it wasn't. :(  First of all it was in a straight script w/o classes, secondly in plain irb. Here's my copy/paste of your code: https://gist.github.com/tjmcewan/a7e4feb2976a93a5eef9

Comment: Yeah, I totally just put a bad example in my code I'm sorry. Try the modified code. It works now...

Comment: @boulder_ruby is there a way to do this with a normal method — as in, not a class method?

Comment: @tekknolagi none of the code above uses class methods. Class methods are declared inside a class by this code `def self.methodnam`. What I've done above is to create *instance* methods via `def methodnam`.

Comment: @boulder_ruby It's been quite some time since I asked that question, but I believe I meant "Can one map over an Enumerable with a method outside of a class?" But it doesn't matter much any more :)

Comment: I need to use multiple attributes inside the map like [1,2,3].map(&plusone,.....), how can do this because I have used it and getting error.

Answer (score 13):

For anyone who needs to visualize it:

[image: Map method example explained visually]

[image: Map that does nothing]

[image: Map that does even less]

[image: Map with a bang!]

Here's the full story:

https://richstone.io/rubys-map-collect-methods-explained-visually/

Answer (score 8):

Using ruby 2.4 you can do the same thing using `transform_values`, this feature extracted from rails to ruby.

```
h = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}

h.transform_values { |v| v * 10 }
 #=> {a: 10, b: 20, c: 30}
```

Answer (score 4):

`0..param_count` means "up to and including param_count".
`0...param_count` means "up to, but not including param_count".

`Range#map` does not return an `Enumerable`, it actually maps it to an array. It's the same as `Range#to_a`.

Answer (score 3):

It "maps" a function to each item in an `Enumerable` - in this case, a range. So it would call the block passed once for every integer from 0 to `param_count` (exclusive - you're right about the dots) and return an array containing each return value.

[Here's the documentation for `Enumerable#map`.](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) It also has an alias, `collect`.

Comment: It's weird, but `Range#map` actually converts it to an array.

Comment: @PedroNascimento: Yeah... that's what I said?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware that map called by itself didn't return an `Enumerable`, like each. I thought it did.

Answer (score 3):

#### `#each`

`#each` runs a function for each element in an array. The following two code excerpts are equivalent:

```rb
x = 10
["zero", "one", "two"].each{|element|
    x++
    puts element
}
```

```rb
x = 10
array = ["zero", "one", "two"]

for i in 0..2
    x++
    puts array[i]
end
```

#### `#map`

`#map` applies a function to each element of an array, returning the resulting array. The following are equivalent:

```rb
array = ["zero", "one", "two"]
newArray = array.map{|element| element.capitalize()}
```

```rb
array = ["zero", "one", "two"]

newArray = []
array.each{|element|
    newArray << element.capitalize()
}
```

#### `#map!`

`#map!` is like `#map`, but modifies the array in place. The following are equivalent:

```rb
array = ["zero", "one", "two"]
array.map!{|element| element.capitalize()}
```

```rb
array = ["zero", "one", "two"]
array = array.map{|element| element.capitalize()}
```

Answer (score 2):

Map is a part of the enumerable module. Very similar to "collect" For Example:

```
  Class Car

    attr_accessor :name, :model, :year

    Def initialize (make, model, year)
      @make, @model, @year = make, model, year
    end

  end

  list = []
  list << Car.new("Honda", "Accord", 2016)
  list << Car.new("Toyota", "Camry", 2015)
  list << Car.new("Nissan", "Altima", 2014)

  p list.map {|p| p.model}
```

Map provides values iterating through an array that are returned by the block parameters.

Comment: map is exactly the same as collect.