# How to reverse the characters of words in an array using Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want to convert the following

```
a = ["hi", "hey", "hello"]
```

into

```
["ih", "yeh", "olleh"];
```

If I use the `.reverse!` it only reverse the list `["hello", "hey", "hi"]`

Comment: Why did you tag Java and Prolog if you want help in Ruby?

Comment: because I need it in those other two languages as well

Comment: So what did you try in Prolog? Code snippets, please!

Comment: `A = ["hi", "hey", "hello"], maplist(reverse,A,B)`.  All best with `set_prolog_flag(double_quotes,chars)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Ruby:

```
a = ["hi", "hey", "hello"]
a.map(&:reverse!)
```

will output:

```
=> ["ih", "yeh", "olleh"]
```

As you need to map the function to each of the values of the array, you can't call `reverse` on the list, but on each element of the list. That's what the `map` function does. The ampersand (`&`) inside the call is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby). For more information about the map function, have a  closer look [on the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084507/what-does-the-map-method-do-in-ruby) or in the official Ruby [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-map).

Comment: Thank you ConcurrentHashMap, I'm new to this forum. sorry for not giving enough details.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yeah, good idea. I've added some cross references to related questions and answers.

Comment: Doing `map(&:reverse!)` is probably not what is desired since `reverse!` is mutating (and its return value is not used). Use `each(&:reverse!)` instead or (preferably) don’t mutate at all with `map(&:reverse)`.

Comment: @Andrew Marshall Thanks for your comment. You're fully right. I only took it as the OP seemed to want to mutate the values.