# Ruby times loop refactoring

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I use Ruby 2.3.

I have code like this, and I want to refactor it and remove result variable.

```
  def place_empty_seats num
    result=''
    num.times do
      result << "<li class='seat non_active'></li>"
    end
    result.html_safe
  end
```

Unfortunately, I do not know the best way to look up refactoring questions besides StackOverflow. At shis moment I have no idea how to make it better, and I'll be very pleased for your input.

Thank you!

Comment: Besides Ilya answer, for more complicated cases, you could use ```map``` method, as described for example in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084507/what-does-the-map-method-do-in-ruby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write like:

```
 def place_empty_seats(num)
    ("<li class='seat non_active'></li>" * num).html_safe
 end
```

in your case.