# Array Method that only outputs the name without instances

Tags: ruby

When I run the command I get
all the song names and then the instances following it. How do I only
get the names?

```
class Song 
    @@all = [] 
    attr_accessor :name 

    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
        @@all << self    
    end 

    def self.all
        @@all  
    end

    def self.print_all_song_names
        @@all.each do |song|
        puts song.name 
        end  
    end 
end 


hotline_bling = Song.new("Hotline Bling")
thriller = Song.new("Thriller")

ninety_nine_problems = Song.new("99 Problems")
thriller = Song.new("Thriller")


puts Song.print_all_song_names
```

Which outputs:

```
Hotline Bling
Thriller
99 Problems
Thriller
#<Song:0x00000000058ced30>
#<Song:0x00000000058cecb8>
#<Song:0x00000000058cebc8>
#<Song:0x00000000058ceb50>
```

Comment: Change  `@@all.each do |song|` to `@@all.map do |song|`. Related question: [How to understand Ruby's .each and .map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39146134/how-to-understand-rubys-each-and-map)

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is your calling `puts` here and there.

The code already calls `puts` in `print_all_song_names`, and after you call `puts Song.print_all_song_names` which roughly means call the method *and* print the value returned.

`each` returns a receiver, which means `print_all_song_names` returns the value of `@@all` class variable. Which gets printed again.

To fix it, just don’t call `puts` in the last line; `Song.print_all_song_names` already prints out everything needed.

```rb
Song.print_all_song_names # voilà
```