# How to access elements of array using index

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an `object` variable that have the following value:

```
[
 {"a"=>nil, "b"=>79, "c"=>"mg/dL", "d"=>"high", "e"=>false},
 {"a"=>80, "b"=>139, "c"=>"mg/dL", "d"=>"low", "e"=>true},
 {"a"=>140, "b"=>199, "c"=>"mg/dL", "d"=>"moderate", "e"=>false}, 
 {"a"=>200, "b"=>nil, "c"=>"mg/dL", "d"=>"high", "e"=>false}
]
```

I am trying to pass the index and get the value of the key `d` but the code crash

```
object.as_json.each_with_index.map { |range, i| range[i].d }
```

I get `undefined method d` for the statement above

How can I get the values of `"d"`?

Answer (score 2):

Access a hash value by using its key.

```
arr.map { |h| h["d"] } #=> ["high", "low", "moderate", "high"]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use the methods `as_json` or `each_with_index`. Using only [map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) is enough. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12084555/1798644) answer, it explains how `map` works.

`object.map { |element| element["d"] }`

Instead of using the [[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) operator of the hash, you can also use [fetch](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) or [dig](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig). `dig` is available from ruby 2.3.

So it can be done like this using `fetch`:
`object.map { |element| element.fetch("d") }`

You can pass an extra parameters to fetch, in case the key `"d"` is missing.

`object.map { |element| element.fetch("d", "") }`

If the key `"d"` is missing in some elements the string `""` is used instead.

And using `dig`
`object.map { |element| element.dig("d") }`