# Get objects only within one array and not multiple arrays within an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, ruby, object

Sorry for the bad English Title but the code below would make more sense.
I used .each to get some keys and values that I wanted from the data but when I do it I get this result.

```
[
  [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Immad",
        age: 18
    }
  ],
  [
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Vicky",
        age: 21
    }
  ],
  [
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Adam",
        age: 24
    }
  ]
]
```

I want to map the objects to some js library for which I want it to be like:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Immad",
        age: 18
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Vicky",
        age: 21
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Adam",
        age: 24
    }
]
```

Can anybody please atleast give me hint what should I use in order to do it using ruby. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I used .each to get some keys and values that I wanted from the data but when I do it I get this result." 1. Please edit your question to include the code you've written so far. 2. What data?

Comment: I have googled it but unable to find any answer on it that solves this, even if someone has answered and you know then please share the link. thanks

Comment: If you're not willing to edit your question to include the code you've written so far and some example data, you're not going to get much help here. Please read my comment again and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @jordan Running
I thought this might be enough to get help.
Well this is the code that I wrote to fetch the title, user name, training schedule date and enrollment url

enrollment_json = enrollments.map {|e| ["title" => "##{e.id} - #{e.user.full_name}", "id" => e.id, "start" => e.training_schedule_date, "end" => e.training_schedule_date, "url" => "#{enrollment_url(e.id)}"] }

Comment: and @anothermh has given the right answer and I was able to fix the code

Comment: Tip: `["title" => ... ]` is not the same as `{ "title" => ... }`.

Comment: Thanks Jordan this should be it. I should have directly used {}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There already is an `Array` method.

```
foo_array.flatten!
```

or non destructive (just a return value `foo_array` remains unchanged)

```
foor_array.flatten
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple, You should do like this

```
Test = [[{:id=>1, :name=>"Immad", :age=>18}], [{:id=>2, :name=>"Vicky", :age=>21}], [{:id=>3, :name=>"Adam", :age=>24}]]
```

Use `.flatten` here.

```
Test.flatten
    => [{:id=>1, :name=>"Immad", :age=>18}, {:id=>2, :name=>"Vicky", :age=>21}, {:id=>3, :name=>"Adam", :age=>24}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.map!`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084507/what-does-the-map-method-do-in-ruby):

```
foo = [
  [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Immad",
        age: 18
    }
  ],
  [
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Vicky",
        age: 21
    }
  ],
  [
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Adam",
        age: 24
    }
  ]
]

# Call .map! on the array
foo.map! { |array| array.first }
=> [
    [0] {
          :id => 1,
        :name => "Immad",
         :age => 18
    },
    [1] {
          :id => 2,
        :name => "Vicky",
         :age => 21
    },
    [2] {
          :id => 3,
        :name => "Adam",
         :age => 24
    }
]
```